# How many virtual interfaces can be added to default lxcbr0 bridge provided by lxc.?

Tags: linux, networking, lxc

I have started making many lxc containers on my host. So by default lxc provides a default bridge lxcbr0. How many virtual interfaces can be instantiated with lxcbr0. I started with 2000 containers,but i got stuck after 1024 containers.

The error being :

```
lxc-start: conf.c: instantiate_veth: 2978 failed to attach 'vethO7X5DJ' to          
the bridge 'lxcbr0': Exchange full
lxc-start: conf.c: lxc_create_network: 3261 failed to create netdev
lxc-start: start.c: lxc_spawn: 826 failed to create the network
lxc-start: start.c: __lxc_start: 1080 failed to spawn 'container_1024'
lxc-start: lxc_start.c: main: 342 The container failed to start.
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the [linux bridge ports limit](https://books.google.com/books?id=ALapr7CvAKkC&pg=PT384&lpg=PT384&dq=linux%20bridge%20ports%20number%201024&source=bl&ots=gVayjQdWNs&sig=I6NSt93ErtjjBvzZFqJ5dJY8b9c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFAQ6AEwB2oVChMI5PyTs-mKyAIViB0-Ch1z7gs6#v=onepage&q=linux%20bridge%20ports%20number%201024&f=false) apparently, which is 1024.

You'll probably need to go with some custom networking (e.g. multiple bridges, as there is no hard limit on bridges) or might be http://openvswitch.org/ or something..

Answer (score 1):

Create one more bridge lxcbr1 and then map lxcbr0 and lxcbr1 using veth interface like

```
 $ ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
 $ brctl addif lxcbr0 veth0
 $ brctl addif lxcbr1 veth1
 $ ifconfig veth0 up
 $ ifconfig veth1 up
```

What we have done is,

1) We create a queue by name veth0 and veth1; so any packet go via veth0 will reach veth1 and vice versa;

2) Then we added both the ends of vethX to lxcbr<0-1> so that all the packet will go to both bridges and all the interfaces connected to this bridges;